# Sharepoint 2010 Versioning limits are not working for minor versions

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, versioning, version-history

I have set 3 minor and 3 major versions to be stored. Major versions work as expected. Oldest is deleted after the 3rd version. However minor versions are kept even when I save the 15th minor version.

Is there a setting I am missing? or is this a bug in 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting for minor versions does not limit the number of minor versions. It limits for how many major versions the minor versions are kept. So, if you set it to 3 and 3, you will always have three major versions an all the minor versions that led to these.

Typically, the second number will be smaller that the first one, like, keep 10 major versions but drafts only for three.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @teylyn is there a way to limit the minor versions and force user to publish a major version whenlimit has been reached?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This is where user education may need to come in. Not every save must be a new minor version. They should check out, edit and save as much as they want and then check in as a new minor version.